# Combinations of coins

Tags: combinatorics

If I have 8 dollars, 7 50c pieces, 4 25c pieces and 3 10c pieces in a container, how many way are there to take 6 coins from the container?

First there are questions which are raised, what if we replace each coin (or conversely we do not), I understand the order in which we choose these coins does not necessarily matter.

If we consider this problem case by case it would take a long time, I was wondering if there was a quicker way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $i$ 10c coins and $j$ 25c coins we can choose the number of 50c coins in  $\{0,1,\ldots,6-i-j\}$ after which the number of dollars is then determined.

Hence the number is
\begin{align*}
\text{num} &= \sum_{i=0}^3 \sum_{j=0}^4 (6-i-j+1) \\
 &= \sum_{i=0}^3 \sum_{j=0}^4 (7-i-j) \\
 &= \left( \sum_{i=0}^3 \sum_{j=0}^4 7 \right) - \left( \sum_{i=0}^3 \sum_{j=0}^4 i+j \right) \\
 &= 140-70 \\
 &= 70.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem with a restriction on quarters and dimes.   First change it to one where you must take one of each kind of coin, so you are selecting 10 coins from 9/8/5/4 and must have at least one of each.  Let there be 10 slots for coins.  You choose three of the nine spaces between the slots to be where the coin type changes, which you can do in $9 \choose 3$ ways.  The dollars go left of the first divider, the half dollars between the first and second, and so on.  Now throw away one of each type of coin and you have the group of six.

Unfortunately, that lets you ask for up to seven dimes or seven quarters in the initial allocation.  You need to count the number of ways to choose ten coins with too many of one kind and subtract those.  The same technique will work, but it will involve some cases.

Comment: If we throw away one of each type of coin, firstly you would have to be careful about which one you're throwing, and then you would also have to consider this for each possibility, from each possibility you would then have to check which of them has less than 0 coins of a certain type. This doesn't seem like a very good way of doing it, is there no other way?

Comment: You said that all the coins of one type are identical.  I added one to make sure there was at least one of each type-that is what makes the $9 \choose 3$ work, because dividers now can't go next to each other.  Until we get to the limit on quarters and dimes it is very easy.

Comment: Ah I see, now how can we work out how many extra dimes and quarters are left?

Comment: It varies with each combination.  Of course, if you know how many dimes and nickels are used, you know. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: How would you count the number of ways to choose 10 coins with too many of one kind? Also what stops us from simply saying we have 22 coins to choose from and we want to pick 6 coins in total, so using $\left(\begin{array}  22  \\ 6 \end{array}\right)$

Comment: Too many is not a problem  We are only concerned about how many of each type we choose.  In the last, you probably meant ${22 \choose 6}$, which would be correct if the coins were all different.  Here if we pick three dollars and three halves, we don't care which dollars and which halves we picked, so that is only one combination, not ${8 \choose 3}{7 \choose 3}